# How to document SNS

Tags: openapi, amazon-sns

HTTP APIs have OpenAPI specs (and Swagger UI)

Has anybody come across a technology or approach for maintaining live documentation of SNS topics and schemas?

Answer (score 0):

Use CloudFormation templates to set up, deploy, and document your Amazon SNS configuration. For example, this is how you would describe a topic in SNS:

```
Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
Properties: 
  ContentBasedDeduplication: Boolean
  DisplayName: String
  FifoTopic: Boolean
  KmsMasterKeyId: String
  Subscription: 
    - Subscription
  Tags: 
    - Tag
  TopicName: String
```

Check more on this [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_SNS.html).
You can also share your YAML or JSON CloudFormation templates, if needed.

Comment: I'm aware how to deploy SNS topics.  The question is how to provide live documentation.  E.g. Swagger documentation for HTTP APIs would look like this: https://petstore.swagger.io/

Comment: I'm aware of Swagger and not aware of live docs out of the box for SNS ;) A workaround would be to leverage CFN as it also documents the aspects of SNS.

Comment: https://www.asyncapi.com/ is probably the closest thing I've come across so far.  If I do anything meaningful with it, I might offer that as an answer (assuming I don't get a better one in the meantime)